# How to call a http service after every 3 seconds in angular 12?

Tags: angular, rxjs

I want to get live data from a database onto a mat grid . I want to refresh the grid with live data every 3 seconds without manually refreshing the page .

I am trying to use subscriptions but it is giving me errors saying no initialization provided .

My TS -

```
  getDataForClients(name:string){
    this.dashboardService.getClientsData(name).subscribe(res=>{
      this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(res);
  })
```

setInterval and timer also giving error outputs .

I have used this is my service -

```
    public getClientsData(name:string){
  return timer(0, 5000)
  .pipe(
     switchMap(_ => this.http.get<any[]>('https://localhost:44395/api/StocksOrders/' + name)),
     catchError(error => of(`Bad request: ${error}`))
  );
}
```

But the output instead of for that passed variable it is giving for all the variables passed till now .
It should only return array with 8 values , but it is returning other arrays as well .

[image]
}

How can i call this method every 3 seconds ?

Comment: which errors setInterval give?

Comment: You can do this with setinterval. if you get errors using this, please specify.

Comment: Specifying in the edit

Comment: Check the edits now please..  @AhmedSHA256

Comment: Maybe try only timer(3000)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

istead of setInterval you should use `interval` from RxJS

```js
import { interval } from 'rxjs';

mySub: Subscription = null;
initializeIntervalDataForClients(name:string){
  if(this.mySub !== null){
    this.mySub.unsubscribe();
  }

  this.mySub = interval(3000).pipe(
    switchMap(i => this.dashboardService.getClientsData(name))
  ).subscribe(
    res => { 
      // do your stuff here 
    }
  );
}
```

Comment: I tried this as well , it works after every 3 seconds but the problem is i am passing the name variable on click of tab change , and it is remembering the previous values and giving results for all the values of names every 3 seconds . Please see the edit in the question i have mentioned .

Comment: you should unsubscribe from the Observable when you change the tab. I updated the example above, it should work.

Comment: mySub (Subscription) cannot be assigned null . What should be the initial value for a subscription ? Without initialization also its not allowing .

Comment: why it cannot be assigned to null?
alternatively you can initialite an empty array and push/pop a subscription in the array.

Comment: Compiler is not allowing to assign null during initialization

Comment: try with: `mySub: Subscription | null = null;`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/245166/discussion-between-sunny-srivastava-and-zerotwelve).

Answer (score 0):

Try this, Its works for me

```
  ngAfterViewInit() {
    setInterval(() => {
      this.getDataForClients("simpleName");
    }, 3000);
  }
```